# Область действия пространства имен php

Tags: php, namespace

Где заканчивается область действия пространства имен в php, объявленного вот так

```
namespace Mynamespace;
//код
```

Продолжается ли она в файле

```
include 'myfile.php';
```

Чем отличается от

```
namespace Mynamespace {
    //код
}
```

Comment: а почему бы вам не проверить это самостоятельно?

Comment: Да я уже подумал... после того как не нашел ответа в Гугле и задал здесь.

Comment: Проверил. 
В пространстве имен Mynamespace создал класс MyClass, константу и переменную. Обратился к ним в файле myfile.php. Класс оказался недоступен, переменная с константой доступны. 
Объявил переменную содержащую объект класса MyClass в Mynamespace.
Обратился к ней в файле myfile.php - переменная доступна.
Как-то странно. Получается, что пространства имен скрывают только имена классов,а переменные и константы остаются глобальными.

Comment: @xlmax, константы принадлежат к неймспейсам, и есть даже хак с переопределением стандартных констант внутри неймспейса (кроме true/false и еще парочки). Переменные не принадлежат к неймспейсам, так как не являются частью объявлений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации разбирается ваш вопрос:

["Импортируемые имена не могут конфликтовать с классами, определенными в том же файле"](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.conflict)

**Upd**. Насчёт синтаксиса с фигурными скобками:

[Описание нескольких пространств имен в одном файле](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)